# Layout folder difference between sw720dp and xlarge

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

What kind of tablets get under `layout-xlarge` and `layout-sw720dp` folders?

For example 8" - 10" goes under `layout-xlarge` folder. It's from documentation:

[image]

But what about `layout-sw720dp` ?

I know that If I haven't `layout-xlarge` folder android will navigate 10" tablet to `layout-sw720dp`, but what about 8" - 9" tablets ?

Android will choose `layout` or `layout-sw720dp` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will pick `layout-sw720dp` folder. According to screen width it will first look for device width larger than 720dp

Answer (score 2):

`layout-sw720dp` means devices with 720dp of smallest width. Specifically, the device's smallestWidth is the shortest of the screen's available height and width.

[From Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)

> **smallestWidth**
>
> Examples:sw320dp, sw600dp, sw720dp etc.     The fundamental size of a
>   screen, as indicated by the shortest dimension of the available screen
>   area. Specifically, the device's smallestWidth is the shortest of the
>   screen's available height and width (you may also think of it as the
>   "smallest possible width" for the screen). You can use this qualifier
>   to ensure that, regardless of the screen's current orientation, your
>   application has at least  dps of width available for its UI.

However if you use both `layout-xlarge` and `layout-sw720dp` in an app, the devices that qualifies both of them will always take from `layout-sw720dp`. This is because of the higher precedence for `sw<???>dp` qualifier. This is clearly specified in the docs which is linked above. If you have given multiple qualifier types for any resources, Android will search for qualifying folders in the order of precedences given to each type.

From the docs

> Android supports several configuration qualifiers and you can add
>   multiple qualifiers to one directory name, by separating each
>   qualifier with a dash.
>   Table lists the valid configuration qualifiers, in order of precedence—if you use multiple qualifiers for
>   a resource directory, you must add them to the directory name in the
>   order they are listed in the table.

Answer (score 1):

> The configuration qualifiers you can use to provide size-specific resources are small, normal, large, and xlarge. For example, layouts for an extra-large screen should go in layout-xlarge/.
>   Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the above size groups are deprecated and you should instead use the swdp configuration qualifier to define the smallest available width required by your layout resources. For example, if your multi-pane tablet layout requires at least 600dp of screen width, you should place it in layout-sw600dp/. Using the new techniques for declaring layout resources is discussed further in the section about Declaring Tablet Layouts for Android 3.2.

Reference 
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

There are multiple folder as bellow you can read about them aswell

```
1)layout-sw480dp drawable-sw480dp

2)layout-sw600dp drawable-sw600dp

3)layout-sw720dp drawable-sw720dp
```